# Extending Promise to support Progress reporting

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

So I wanted to extend Promise to have a 'progress' part so that i can report progrss with it while using Promise for my Async tasks.

Thus I extended Promise like this:

```
class promisePro extends Promise {
    constructor(fn) {
        super(function (resolve, reject) {
            fn(resolve, reject, this._progress.bind(this));
        });
    }

    _progress(v) {
        if (this.progressCB)
            this.progressCB(v);
    }

    progress(fn) {
        this.progressCB = fn;
    }
}
```

and used it:

```
function ptest() {
    return new promisePro((resolve, reject, progress) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            progress(0.3)
        }, 1000)
        setTimeout(() => {
            progress(0.6)
        }, 2000)
        setTimeout(() => {
            progress(0.9)
        }, 3000)
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(1)
        }, 4000)
    })
}
```

and used itt:

```
ptest().then((r) => {
    console.log('finiished: ' + r)
}).progress((p) => {
    console.log('progress: ' + p)
})
```

and got this error:

```
ptest().then((r) => {
    ^
TypeError: Promise resolve or reject function is not callable
```

What am i doing wrong here?

I was using node 7.5, updated to 8.4. Got that error in both versions.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps take a look at [`progress-promise`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/progress-promise).

Comment: @robertklep ill look at that but more than finding a solution i want to know how to fix my code, im learning node/js u know

Comment: I would recommend not to extend `Promise` with a subclass for this. Directing progress notifications does not compose well in the way promises do, it would require a separate abstraction (like the `all` and `sequence` custom methods in the linked "progress-promise" package do). The simplest and most flexible solution is to just pass a progress callback into functions that return normal promises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are a couple of issues to look out for here.

firstly, the "this" keyword is undefined until the super function is called. therefore you could change the constructor to something like below, using a function to reference an instantiated variable to sel

```
constructor(fn) {
    let self;
    super(function (resolve, reject) {
        fn(resolve, reject, value => self._progress(value));
    });
    self = this;
}
```

secondly, keep in mind you are extending the promise type, so when you are calling the "then" function on it, it will return a **new** promise object, not your new promise type, so the progress function is undefined there. a way to avoid this is to return "this" in the progress function, and in the usage to use the progress function before then, as below

```
progress(fn) {
    this.progressCB = fn;
    return this;
}
```

and for the usage

```
ptest().progress((p) => {
    console.log('progress: ' + p)
}).then((r) => {
    console.log('finiished: ' + r)
})
```

but now you will lose the benefit of the promise and won't be able to chain more promises with progress (still, depends on your use case).

As a suggestion for a different approach, have you tried using Observables?
http://reactivex.io/rxjs/

Comment: Thanks man
I didnt know this is undefined before super call ! fixing that that "Promise resolve or reject function is not callable" error fixed, tough i donno what was relation of that message to the real problem ...

Comment: Debug the original code by removing pieces of code, specificaly the progress call, youll get a message saying cannot find _progress of undefined

Comment: thanks,   
as for then-progress-chain problem, i added a "then" to my class:
        then(fn){
            super.then(fn)
            return this;
        }
donno if its a good idea, but solved my problem.
considering im a noob in js, is this a good solution?

Comment: It wont behave as expected because you dont return a new promise but just the same, cant think of a good solution. Perhaps look at an existing implementation as @robertklep suggested and see how it could be done

Comment: @Tal You don't need that `self` variable, the `this` keyword works fine inside an arrow function as long as it's not called before `super` returns.

Comment: "*calling the "then" function will return a new promise object, not your new promise type*" - actually that's wrong, `then` will happily create an instance of the subtype. It will not know what the do with the progress callback, of course, but that's a different problem.

Comment: @Bergi regarding the `this` in the constructor i actually don't think it will work because there wouldn't be a binded `this` in the function's context. regarding the `then` function, without any specific implementation wouldn't `then` return `new Promise`? it is not aware of the promisePro type

Comment: @Tal Try it, it'll work :-) `this` isn't bound in the function's context, that's the whole point. `then` is aware of the current instance and will use its constructor.